# Having trouble with SQL Query to JSP Page

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to write some JAVA to send an SQL query and then return that data back as a table in a JSP page.  The code in JAVA itself works fine outputting to the console, but when I attempt to put into the JSP page for a table, it just ignores it.

The following is the code I have for the JSP page:

```
<%@page import="entd481.week3_v2_miller.DB"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <body>
        
          <table align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
               <tr bgcolor="#A52A2A">
                    <td><b>Customer ID</b></td>
                    <td><b>First Name</b></td>
                    <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
                    <td><b>E-Mail</b></td>
                    <td><b>Phone</b></td>

                    <%       
                         String url = "jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:XXXX/XXXXXXXX";
                         String username = "XXXXXXX";
                         String password = "XXXXXXXXX";
                         String query = "SELECT * FROM XXXXXXX.Customers;";
             
                         try {
                              Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                              Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                              ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                              while (rs.next()) {
                                   String customerID = rs.getString("Customer_ID");
                                   String firstName = rs.getString("FirstName");
                                   String lastName = rs.getString("LastName");
                                   String email = rs.getString("email");
                                   String phoneNumber = rs.getString("PhoneNumber"); 
                
                                   out.print("<tr>");
                                   out.print("<td>" + customerID + "</td>");
                                   out.print("<td>" + firstName + "</td>");
                                   out.print("<td>" + lastName + "</td>");
                                   out.print("<td>" + email + "</td>");
                                   out.print("<td>" + phoneNumber + "</td>");
                                   out.print("</tr>");                 
                              }
                              st.close();
                              conn.close();
                         }   
                         catch (Exception e) {
                              System.out.println(e);            
                         }
                    %>
          </table>
     </body>
</html>
```

Printing out to the console (from the JAVA code standpoint) works great - get all the contents of the DB.  But I am stuck as to why when I run this, the resulting page is blank for results, and none of the HTML that I am telling it to out.print is coming through.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be missing `</table>`, but I'm not sure that that would cause your problem.  Have you tried looking at the HTML source for the page after it is rendered?  It's not clear to me whether the HTML is not being generated at all, or whether the browser is just not showing it in the way you expect.

Comment: Yes, I do have the </table> in it.  (Sorry, was trying to clean up all the comments and things I have tried / commented out for ease of readability.)  As far as the HTML goes, yes - when I view the page source, the HTML just isn't there.  As if anything that is a result of the out.print lines I have was just simply not generated.

Comment: OK, then I'm wondering if an exception got thrown when you tried to connect to your database.  I see you're printing a stack trace to the log.  Did you look at the log?  Or if you can't find the right log to look at, try changing `System.out.println(e);` to `out.print(e);` which will let you see the exception in the page itself.  That might give you a clue as to what's happening.  It might, for example, be a DNS error or something that prevents the application server from finding the database server.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - Thank you for that info.  Yes, I am now seeing the error, "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:", and am attempting to read some of the other questions where this was answered, but quite frankly, it seems a little tricky to find.  I found a driver and loaded it in the Tomcat lib folder, but I am still getting the error.

Comment: OK, if you've found a jar for the mysql driver, added it to the tomcat lib folder, and restarted tomcat; then I don't know why you'd still get the exception.  Maybe you could try building that same jar into the application itself.  If that doesn't work, definitely ask a new question here.  Somebody smarter than me might be able to figure it out.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - Ok, thanks to your help, I solved it.  I needed to insert a dependency in my pom.xml file and also add the Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") line.

Answer (score 0):

Was missing a dependency in the pom.xml file, and resolved with the following:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.39</version>
 </dependency>
```

Then, had to additionally add the following code on the JSP page for DB connectivity:

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

All seems to be working now.  Thanks to @DawoodibnKareem for pointing me in the right direction.